# Flutter: Fetch YouTube video title

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, plugins

In my project, I need to show the title of the YouTube video shared by the user. I found a plugin youtube_player_flutter for playing videos but I can not fetch the title of that video to show on UI. Any help or suggestion will be appreciable.

Here is my code:

```
Future<void> getYouTubeInfo({String url, int index}) async {
String id = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(url);
LinkUrl urlVal = LinkUrl(url: url, img: 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/$id/0.jpg', title: '');
feedDetailBloc.addYouTubeScrap(url: url, index: index, linkUrl: urlVal);
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please add the code for what you have done till now..?

Comment: @AsimJawad, I have added the code.